# Foreign key solo a objetos que cumplan una condición

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Tengo los siguientes dos modelos:

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class VideoMaterials(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    videos_id = models.ForeignKey(Videos, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Videos_id')
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer que en el panel de administración `/admin/` solo me permita seleccionar como `videos_id` solo a aquellos videos que cumplan una condición determinada? Como por ejemplo, que su `title` sea mayor a 3 letras.

Comment: ¿Qué estás haciendo para resolver tu problema? Por favor muestra el contenido de la configuración de tu panel, es decir, el archivo `admin.py`.

Comment: No tengo nada en admin.py aparte de los registers(), estuve buscando las limitaciones con list_filter pero no hay un solo ejemplo que no sea complejo o se ajuste a mis necesidades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí resolví el problema haciendo uso de [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to), donde tuve que agregarle un poco de código cuando se quiere utilizar con atributos property, acá dejo un ejemplo para el caso que mencioné en la pregunta por si a alguien le sirve:

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    def mayor_3_letras(self):
        return len(self.title) > 3

    titulo_con_mas_de_3_letras = property(mayor_3_letras) # Atributo property


# Esta funcion debe retornar un diccionario o un Q object (sacado de la documentación oficial)
def limitar_opciones():
    lista_de_pks = [obj.pk for obj in Videos.objects.all() if obj.titulo_con_mas_de_3_letras == True] # De esta forma puedo filtrar los elementos por su atributo property
    return Q(pk__in = lista_de_pks)

class VideoMaterials(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    videos_id = models.ForeignKey(Videos, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Videos_id', limit_choices_to = limitar_opciones)
```

Comment: Recuerda que puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Sisi, gracias por recordarmelo, estoy esperando que se cumplan los dos días obligatorios. Mañana la marco sin falta, saludos y gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Los dos días se refieren a ofrecer una recompensa. La respuesta la puedes aceptar inmediatamente.

Comment: No se por qué pero acá me está diciendo que puedo aceptar mi propia respuesta mañana :/

Comment: Ah cierto... Tienes razón.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente hay otras opciones, pero la más económica, en el entendido que no tienes nada, es crear un campo para almacenar la longitud del título y poder usarlo como filtro en el admin.

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    longitud = models.IntegerField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.longitud = len(self.title)
        super(Videos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Ahora, cada vez que guardes un registro, se actualizará la longitud. Y no es editable, así que no aparece en los formularios.

Si ya tu modelo ya tiene datos, puedes colocar cualquier valor al hacer la migración.

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations videos
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'longitud' to videos without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>> 3
Migrations for 'videos':
  videos/migrations/0002_videos_longitud.py:
    - Add field longitud to videos
```

Y actualizar los datos recorriendo tu modelo.

```
In [1]: from videos.models import Videos

In [2]: for v in Videos.objects.all():
   ...:     v.save()
   ...:
```

Si te interesan otras opciones, puedes investigar sobre [Custom Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/) solo toma en cuenta que al usar el método que te propongo, solo calculas la longitud al guardar el registro, y al usar propiedades o gestores personalizados, harás el cálculo cada vez que pidas un registro.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tomarte la molestia de responder, pero lo que yo busco es que no me aparezcan los videos que tengan el titulo de longitud <= 3 al momento de seleccionar el `videos_id` de VideoMaterials

Comment: jeje Ok. Está muy bien.